# Angular 10 change native element scroll left value trigger change detection multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

This is my code:

```
@ViewChild('list') list: ElementRef; // Div with elements inside

// I call this method in view
next() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      const width = this.list?.nativeElement?.offsetWidth;
      this.list.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.list?.nativeElement?.scrollLeft + width;
    });
  }
```

The scroll works fine, but depending on the new value in scroll left:

```
this.list.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.list?.nativeElement?.scrollLeft + width;
```

the change detection is trigger multiple times.
Is there a way for angular to run change detection only once?

The component is in OnPush Change Detection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I call this method in view` => does it mean you are calling this method from HTML ?

Comment: @micronyks exactly!